# Compare: Which is bigger? $3^{\sqrt2}$ or $2^{\sqrt 3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, inequality

> Compare: Which is bigger?
>
> $\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$ $\Large{3^{\sqrt2}}\quad$ or  $\quad \Large{2^{\sqrt 3}}$

My attempts:

Let,  $\quad$ $a=3^{\sqrt 2}$ and $b=2^{\sqrt 3}$

We have

> $$a^\sqrt{3}=3^\sqrt{6}\\ b^\sqrt{3}=8<3^{\sqrt{4}}<3^\sqrt{6}=a^\sqrt{3} $$
>
> $$a^\sqrt{3}>b^\sqrt{3} \Longrightarrow a>b$$

Question-1:

- Is my solution correct?

Question-2:

- I saw the following solution was approved on another site.  But, the last line seems wrong to me. Am I right? [image]

Comment: $$\left(3^\sqrt2\right)^\sqrt3>\left(3^\sqrt2\right)^\sqrt2=3^2=9>8=2^3=\left(2^\sqrt3\right)^\sqrt3$$

Comment: @DonThousand Can you answer my $2$ exact questions?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an acceptable topic for a comment, but how do you write your letter b's?

Comment: @heepo This is not my solution..( in the picture)

Comment: The solution you have typed out is correct, but the handwritten solution in the image is (i) different, (ii) incorrect. To add to the confusion, the problem itself seems an odd one, because $3^{\sqrt2}$ is *much* bigger than $2^{\sqrt3}.$ You may be intrigued by this much closer comparison: [What is bigger: $\sqrt2^{\sqrt3^{\sqrt3}}$ or $\sqrt3^{\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}}$?] \url{https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3457363}. Perhaps more than one transcription error has taken place here?

Comment: So if the left exponent is higher than the right exponent then automatically the left number is higher than the right number, without knowing anything about their bases? How can that be right?

Comment: I think confusion may have arisen partly because you wrote "My attempts" - plural - which tends to make the reader expect that both of the solutions will be yours, possibly variants of the same argument. (By the way, I'm sorry that one of my comments got a bit garbled. I literally couldn't see it - see [Comments containing MathJax are not being displayed fully](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30982).)

Comment: "I think confusion may have arisen partly because you wrote "My attempts" - plural - which tends to make the reader expect that both of the solutions will be yours, possibly variants of the same argument."  ... Still that is no reason to close!  If an OP did an excercise and got two different answers that's a *perfectly* valid question!

Comment: @fleablood Happens to me all the time. :)

Comment: @fleablood Yes, in other words $\sqrt3 >0$ and $\sqrt2>0$ .Then the solution may be a perfect.

Comment: $2, 3 > 1$ and $\sqrt 3, \sqrt 2 > 0$ so $2^{\sqrt 3}, 3^{\sqrt 2} > 1$.  And if $a,b > 1$ we can conclude that if $a^k > b^k\implies.....$ ..... *OOOOOPS* MY BAD!!!!!  We can conclude that even if $a, b < 1$.  ... How embarrassing!  My face is red.  Ignore my comment it is wrong.  I was confusing if $k > 1$ then $k^a > k^b \iff a >b$ with if $k > 0$ then $a^k > b^k \iff a > b$.   .... oops... ignore my comment!

Comment: That *is* a compelling reason to close, so I won't be voting to reopen. The confusion isn't entirely my fault. I literally can't read comments containing MathJax at all. The one available workaround stops working as soon as any editing is done. The title of the other question is so garbled that I didn't even know it *was* the title of a question, when I did briefly glimpse it!

Comment: @CalumGilhooley This question is not the question of finding a awesome closed form for an extraordinarily complicated integral. If this question is closed, what if it does not close ?! (English is not my native language)

Comment: Closing a question as a duplicate of another is not a criticism of it. Of course, one can debate whether this and the other question are exact duplicates of each other. Also this question is far better formulated then the other one. But later questions do tend to be closed even when they are improvements on earlier ones. (I'm all argued out. I hope I'm still making some sense! And just to repeat, in case of any lingering misunderstanding, or any new misunderstanding: I still see nothing at all wrong with this question.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Never mind. Not important. I used to love doing math before. Then I had bad habits. My head then stopped working well. What matters to me is how can I get better? I don't intend to be Terence Tao. I already can't. I'm just looking for ways to get better. They say meditation sounds good for the healthy functioning of our head.Anyway, I spoke irrelevant.  The important thing is to go forward. Best Regars..!

Comment: I also got into bad mathematical habits, and am trying (late in life, although not for the first time) to get better. I find it helps to stick around MSE, in spite of frustrations and discouragements of various kinds. (It also helps to take an occasional break!) Doing so seems to improve my mathematical "common sense", which isn't easy to pick up by reading textbooks, brooding about foundational matters (which I do a *lot*), or even taking formal assessed courses. Perhaps you can formulate your difficulties as a question on Mathematics Educators SE? (I haven't yet thought how to do so myself.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Now I confused what are bad mathematical habits?Maybe Did you mean only bad habits?. Do I understand correct?

Comment: The most likely thing is that I misunderstood what you meant, in the comment I was replying to. (These are deep matters to discuss in comments on a mathematical question! The system is already reminding us to "avoid extended discussions in comments". I doubt if I have any enlightenment to offer, anyway!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handwritten one is simply the wrong approach.  If you raise $a$ and $b$ to *different* powers you simply will not (usually) be able to conclude anything by comparing the results.  How can you?  You raised them to different powers so whatever inequality you get doesn't relate to the original values in any way!

Everything it came up with is true (but not helpful)  up to $a^{\sqrt 3} > b^{\sqrt 2}$ this has been shown[1].  But the conclusion just doesn't make sense.

$a^{\sqrt 3} > b^{\sqrt 2} \not \implies a =b$(!!!!)

Why would it?  $\sqrt 2 \ne \sqrt 3$.

This is like claiming $3^3 > 4^2 \implies 3 > 4$.

(Or simply if $a = 2.99$ and $b = 3.01$ then  $2.99^{\sqrt 3} \approx  6.6663278104352795010160893782624$ while $3.01^{\sqrt 2}\approx 4.7511115647726528859943327888079$.

(So $a^{\sqrt 3} > b^{\sqrt 2} $ but $a < b$.)

$a^{bigger number} > b^{smallernumber}$ doesn't tell us anything.[2]

We *could* try

$a^{\sqrt 3} > b^{\sqrt 2} \implies a > b^{\frac {\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}}$

or

$a^{\sqrt 3} > b^{\sqrt 2} \implies a^{\frac {\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 2}} > b$

but we can't get anywhere from there.

....

But yours is fine.

=======

[1](It is nothing more than claiming $3^{\sqrt 6} > 2^{\sqrt 6}$.

[2] However if we got the *other* result $a^{smaller power} > b^{biggerpower}$ (*and* if we know $a, b > 1$) we *can* conclude $a > b$ because

a) $a^{biggerpower} > a^{smallerpower} > b^{bigger power}$

b) $a^{smallerpower} > b^{biggerpower} > b^{smallerpower}$.

But if the powers and the inequality are in disagreement, we don't know which "overpowers" the other.

This is assuming $a, b > 1$.  If $a,b < 1$ the exact *OPPOSITE* applies.

And if you don't *know* if $a,b$ are bigger smaller than $1$ then you can't compare different powers at all because you don't know anything.  That's another reason the handwritten one was the wrong approach.